# Как найти линейную зависимость в данных?

Tags: python, pandas, статистика, анализ-данных, линейная-алгебра

Хочу отобрать наиболее важные признаки (вещественные и категориальные). Первым шагом, нахожу те, которые наиболее коррелированы с целевой переменной и те, корреляция которых меньше порога (гиперпараметр), отбрасываю. Следующим шагом хотелось бы отбросить те, которые линейно зависимы.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, каким образом найти линейно зависимые признаки в данных (с какой–то погрешностью)?

Сейчас делаю так: считаю взаимную корреляцию `Pandas.DataFrame.corr()`, затем собираю группы, для которых взаимная корреляция больше порога, и оставляю только один элемент из каждой группы в итоговых данных.

PS [ссылка на данные...](https://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup/view/kdd-cup-2009/Data)

Comment: Исходные данные как обычно [отсюда](https://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup/view/kdd-cup-2009/Data)?

Comment: @MaxU Да, совершенно верно :)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы попробовал следующий подход:

1. избавляемся от признаков (столбцов), в которых процентное соотношение отсутствующих значений (`NaN`) больше заданного порога (70%)
2. конвертируем все категориальные данные в числовые данные: ('слово1' -> 1, 'слово2' -> 2, и т.д.). Предварительно заменим все редко встречаемые слова на `NaN`, чтобы уменьшить размер словаря слов.

Полный код:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2, SelectKBest, RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder, MultiLabelBinarizer


try:
    from pathlib import Path
except ImportError:
    from pathlib2 import Path


#######################
WORK_DIR = Path(r'D:\data\gDrive\My.Documents\Work\ML\SO\928875-Feature_selection')
notna_thresh = 0.3
#os.chdir(str(WORK_DIR))
#######################

def get_data(filename, _sep='\t', dtyp='number',
             notna_thresh=0.3, **kwargs):
    kwargs['sep'] = kwargs.pop('sep', _sep)    
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, **kwargs).select_dtypes(dtyp)
    # drop columns with the high percentage of NaN's
    # a column should have at least [notna_thresh] not NaN values
    return df.loc[:, df.notna().mean() >= notna_thresh]


def prep_num_data(df):
    impute = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
    scale = StandardScaler()
    # fill missing data with the mean values, scale data
    df = pd.DataFrame(
            scale.fit_transform(impute.fit_transform(df)), 
            columns=df.columns, 
            index=df.index)
    return df


def prep_cat_data(df, min_freq=10):
    # series of all categorical words/tokens
    words = pd.Series(df.values.ravel(), index=df.values.ravel())
    # select all SPAM tokens with the frequency < [min_freq]
    tmp = (words.value_counts() < min_freq)
    spam = tmp[tmp].index
    # replace all SPAM tokens with NaN
    words.loc[words.isin(spam)] = np.nan
    df.loc[:,:] = words.values.reshape(df.shape)
    # encode all tokens
    le = LabelEncoder()
    df = df.fillna('')
    scale = StandardScaler()
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = le.fit_transform(df[col])
    df = pd.DataFrame(scale.fit_transform(df),
                      columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
    return df


tmp = get_data(WORK_DIR / 'orange_small_train.data', dtyp='number',
               notna_thresh=notna_thresh)
train = prep_num_data(tmp)

tmp = get_data(WORK_DIR / 'orange_small_train.data', dtyp='object',
               notna_thresh=notna_thresh)
train = train.join(prep_cat_data(tmp))
del tmp

labels = pd.read_csv(WORK_DIR / 'orange_large_train_churn.labels', header=None, squeeze=True)
```

результат:

```
In [73]: train
Out[73]:
           Var6          Var7     Var13         Var21         Var22     Var24    ...       Var223    Var225    Var226    Var227    Var228    Var229
0      0.078791  3.193535e-02 -0.404348  4.302500e-01  4.335933e-01  1.033675    ...     2.520512 -0.835461  2.049586 -0.118735 -0.342471 -0.789922
1     -0.316420 -1.141517e+00 -0.474163 -1.247134e-01 -1.200804e-01 -0.273110    ...    -0.282632 -0.835461  0.669891 -0.118735 -0.342471 -0.789922
2      1.543559  3.193535e-02 -0.131163  1.832657e+00  1.832742e+00  2.340460    ...     2.520512  1.307021 -0.019957 -2.422921  2.205763  0.461539
3      0.000000 -1.141517e+00 -0.474163  5.328719e-17 -4.343277e-01  0.000000    ...    -0.282632 -0.835461 -0.537343 -0.118735 -0.342471 -0.789922
4     -0.117433  3.193535e-02  0.746067 -3.197006e-01 -3.146144e-01 -0.055313    ...    -0.282632  1.307021 -0.537343 -0.118735 -0.342471  1.713000
...         ...           ...       ...           ...           ...       ...    ...          ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
49995 -0.382749 -1.141517e+00 -0.474163 -1.922090e-01 -1.874191e-01 -0.273110    ...    -0.282632 -0.835461 -1.227191 -0.118735 -0.342471 -0.789922
49996 -0.098087 -1.141517e+00  0.563943  2.727603e-01  2.764697e-01 -0.273110    ...    -0.282632  1.307021 -0.537343 -0.118735 -1.322561  0.461539
49997  0.584550  3.193535e-02  0.079797  6.252371e-01  6.281273e-01 -0.055313    ...    -0.282632  0.235780  0.669891 -0.118735  0.637619 -0.789922
49998  0.000000 -1.488907e-16  0.000000  5.328719e-17  8.506137e-17  0.000000    ...    -0.282632 -0.835461 -0.537343 -0.118735 -0.342471 -0.789922
49999  0.145120  3.193535e-02 -0.159999 -7.971642e-02 -7.518797e-02 -0.490907    ...    -0.282632 -0.835461  2.049586 -0.118735 -0.342471 -0.789922

[50000 rows x 74 columns]

In [74]: train.corr()
Out[74]:
            Var6      Var7     Var13     Var21     Var22     Var24    ...       Var223    Var225    Var226    Var227    Var228    Var229
Var6    1.000000  0.148626  0.094397  0.576973  0.575632  0.419153    ...     0.073249  0.081602  0.009811  0.031508  0.035746  0.081132
Var7    0.148626  1.000000  0.406322  0.063691  0.067912  0.065608    ...     0.165245  0.347809 -0.009406  0.095391  0.149346  0.339736
Var13   0.094397  0.406322  1.000000  0.048067  0.049612  0.034296    ...     0.128005  0.239335 -0.006843  0.081847  0.133104  0.219824
Var21   0.576973  0.063691  0.048067  1.000000  0.997676  0.668110    ...     0.038996  0.025777  0.009488  0.011548  0.010669  0.022661
Var22   0.575632  0.067912  0.049612  0.997676  1.000000  0.671668    ...     0.040884  0.028954  0.008881  0.012926  0.011426  0.025552
...          ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...    ...          ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
Var225  0.081602  0.347809  0.239335  0.025777  0.028954  0.046428    ...     0.249432  1.000000 -0.058574  0.117028  0.162998  0.578941
Var226  0.009811 -0.009406 -0.006843  0.009488  0.008881  0.006240    ...    -0.005086 -0.058574  1.000000 -0.006991 -0.003561 -0.008461
Var227  0.031508  0.095391  0.081847  0.011548  0.012926  0.017921    ...     0.057642  0.117028 -0.006991  1.000000  0.077523  0.120345
Var228  0.035746  0.149346  0.133104  0.010669  0.011426  0.018802    ...     0.059966  0.162998 -0.003561  0.077523  1.000000  0.168008
Var229  0.081132  0.339736  0.219824  0.022661  0.025552  0.047828    ...     0.214778  0.578941 -0.008461  0.120345  0.168008  1.000000

[74 rows x 74 columns]
```

PS это не отвечает на вопрос о линейной зависимости, но это решение существенно сокращает набор признаков - до `74`.

Далее можно анализировать корреляцию признаков используя `DataFrame.corr()` или сразу конвертировать полученные данные в `N` самых значимых признаков, воспользовавшись [методом главных компонент](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82).

Синтезированные признаки - это не просто выборка `N` самых значимых признаков из исходного набора данных - это новый набор данных с `N` столбцами, в котором мы потеряли наименьшее количество информации.

Пример:

```
In [57]: pca = PCA(n_components=50)

In [58]: X = pca.fit_transform(train)

In [59]: pca.explained_variance_
Out[59]:
array([8.78111707, 4.61801991, 3.56311825, 2.65682273, 2.14257791, 2.08297395, 2.01758999, 1.8897215 , 1.79855392, 1.63387916, 1.57638672, 1.41175942
, 1.35784778, 1.29132313, 1.21377284, 1.15978217,
       1.12668213, 1.09080082, 1.06111481, 1.04591207, 1.0307829 , 1.02024448, 1.00145705, 0.98589089, 0.97746531, 0.97280662, 0.94090933, 0.91201182
, 0.8994212 , 0.88963737, 0.87422332, 0.86328647,
       0.83493594, 0.8282582 , 0.81561919, 0.80281115, 0.79499388, 0.76968098, 0.76093363, 0.74503073, 0.73063365, 0.70033651, 0.68874308, 0.66798021
, 0.65073396, 0.64772106, 0.6341183 , 0.6232895 ,
       0.57455148, 0.54317828])

In [61]: train.var().sum()
Out[61]: 74.00148002960213

In [62]: pca.explained_variance_.sum()
Out[62]: 67.70144277632272
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, насколько справедливо в этом случае использование `LabelEncoder `? Как я понимаю, он преобразует строки в числа, на которых будет определен порядок (1 меньше 2), хотя в исходных данных (строки) отношения порядка нет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, было бы неплохо попробовать разные подходы. Но как вы уже знаете данный "дата сет" слишком большой для "One Hot Encoding". Кроме того он очень дисбалансирован - 93% одного класса (-1) ит только 7% (1) - это усложняет обучение. В общем мой подход не очень удачный - модель предсказывает практически только (-1). Думаю я удалил какие-то важные данные, по которым можно предсказывать класс (1). В общем с данными нужно работать дальше... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Проверим предсказания на обработанных данных из [другого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/929033/211923), воспользовавшись [sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

Для проверки правильности разобъем обучающую выборку на две части (66% и 33%) - большую часть будем использовать для обучения, меньшую для проверки.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

def score(X, Y, test_size=0.33):
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = \
        train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size)
    lr = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
    lr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    return lr.score(X_test, Y_test)

Y_churn = pd.read_csv(WORK_DIR / 'orange_large_train_churn.labels', header=None, squeeze=True)
Y_upselling = pd.read_csv(WORK_DIR / 'orange_small_train_upselling.labels', header=None, squeeze=True)
Y_appetency = pd.read_csv(WORK_DIR / 'orange_small_train_appetency.labels', header=None, squeeze=True)
```

Результат на обработанных данных (без уменьшения размерности выборки):

```
In [143]: print('Churn score: {:.3f}'.format(score(train, Y_churn)))
Churn score: 0.928

In [144]: print('Upselling score: {:.3f}'.format(score(train, Y_upselling)))
Upselling score: 0.930

In [145]: print('Appetency score: {:.3f}'.format(score(train, Y_appetency)))
Appetency score: 0.981
```

Результат на обработанных данных после уменьшения размерности выборки:

```
In [150]: pca = PCA(n_components=50)

In [151]: X = pca.fit_transform(train)

In [152]: print('Churn score: {:.3f}'.format(score(X, Y_churn)))
Churn score: 0.928

In [153]: print('Upselling score: {:.3f}'.format(score(X, Y_upselling)))
Upselling score: 0.924

In [154]: print('Appetency score: {:.3f}'.format(score(X, Y_appetency)))
Appetency score: 0.984
```

Размерности выборок:

```
In [155]: train.shape
Out[155]: (50000, 74)

In [156]: X.shape
Out[156]: (50000, 50)
```